# Sqlite3 pseudo-index column based on alphabetical sort

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, indexing

In Sqlite3, how can I create a pseudo-index column with sequential row numbers based on an alphabetical sort of another column in the same table?

So far, I've been wrestling with very complicated SQL queries to solve simple problems in a python web application.

I just want to iterate through records (next-previous scenarios) without messing with indexes and dealing with non-sequential record numbers.

Simply stated, I have a table with a "title" column and a "record_id" column. (40 columns total)

It's a small table of only about 250 records. The titles are very long and there are missing record_id numbers where records have been deleted. I only add or delete a record about once a month (using DB Browser for SQLite) and I don't insert records, just add them at the end, auto-incrementing the record_id.

I thought why not add a "title_sort_order" (integer) column to the table based on an alphabetical sort of the title column, and then just renumber it when I rarely add or delete a record?

I know how to do this kind of thing, using an f-string (in this case for "previous"):

```
f"SELECT record_id, title FROM { table } 
INDEXED BY { titles_index } 
WHERE title < '{ current_title_text }' 
ORDER BY title DESC LIMIT 1;"
```

Which is very cumbersome.

There are many complicated solutions on StackOverflow for "next-previous" issues (such as where I found the above) but a new column would be much simpler.

The table already has a column: `title_sort(int)`

I had the idea to write a little python script to read the table, with something like this pseudo code:

```
table_data = SELECT rowid, title FROM { table } 
INDEXED BY { titles_index } 
ORDER BY title ASC;

order = 1

for each row in table_data

    UPDATE { table }

    SET row.title_sort = order

    order = order + 1
```

But I'm struggling with the code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: If you guys don't know how to do it, just say so. You're not adding value if you just want to do a drive-by and take a shot at me or at Sqlite. I explained the whys and wherefores quite sufficiently, which already answers the questions you ask. Maybe read before commenting or don't comment at all.

Comment: What's the point of an ID column that changes when other rows are touched?  How would you even use this?  Once a record has an ID, it should have that ID forever.  If you need to enumerate rows, do that when you query, not as an additional column.

Comment: It's not an ID column. The record_id never changes. I would us the "title sort" column to sort the titles without using an index, such as in the complicated query above, and not have to worry about "outside of range" issues or missing records. If I knew how to create this new column in SQL for sqlite3, I could just do a quick renumbering when I add or delete a record, which is rare.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this the normal and expected way, by using ORDER BY when you query?  What you're talking about seems like a lot of overhead for something the language natively supports.  If you have so many rows that ORDER BY becomes a burden, then perhaps you should move away from SQLite to a real database solution.

Comment: A real database solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. As a n00b at sqlite I'm sure the steps are extremely inefficient, but they work. The pseudo-index field is "title_sort". I just created a flask route and a test page. Navigating to the route updates the table, and the page shows the results.

Now in my application when I display a record, at the top there is a widget that shows the current record_id, title and sort position, plus the "previous" record_id and title, and the "next" record_id and title. Previous and Next are based on the alphabetical sort order rather than record_id.

```
import sqlite3
from flask import render_template

@app.route("/sort")
def sort():
    index = "ix_title"

    # Get the rows in alphabetical order of "title" column. 
    # Selecting "title" is used for diagnostics
    statement_1 = f"SELECT rowid, title FROM { table } INDEXED BY { index } ORDER BY title ASC"

    conn = sqlite3.connect(PRACTICE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(statement_1)
    row_data = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    # Now use "row_data" (indexed by title) from above to cycle through
    # the table a row at a time, populating the title_sort column
    # "row_data" type is a list of tuples.  

    order = 1
    for row in row_data:
        # inside the tuple, row[0] will be the rowid from the query above
        statement2 = f"UPDATE { table } SET title_sort = { order } WHERE rowid = { row[0] }"
        conn = sqlite3.connect(PRACTICE)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(statement_2)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    
# to test whether it worked correctly, grab the updated rows and send to a page

    statement_3 = f"SELECT title_sort, rowid, title FROM { table } ORDER BY title_sort ASC"
    conn = sqlite3.connect(PRACTICE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(statement_3)
    sort_test = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    return render_template("/sort.html", 
        row_data=row_data, 
        sort_test=sort_test)
```